# Find the kernel of the following transformation

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb P_2 \rightarrow \mathbb P_2$
be defined by $T(at^2 + bt + c) = 2at + b.$ Find $\ker T$.

Use $a, b, c$ and $d$ in your answer in the form $[x]t^2 + [y]t + [z].$

I am unsure how to approach this problem, and if someone can give me a really precise definition of a kernel (as I can't seem to grasp it yet) that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f \in \ker T $ means $Tf = 0.$ in your case you are looking for quadratic function that give you zero derivative. i.e., only constant function will do that. therefore a bsis for $\ker T$ is $\{ 1 \}$.